# Printing - how to force itemssource update?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, printing

I have my custom Control which is sudoku grid. It acts like any itemscontrol like listbox or combobox. Items are Cells. Items are bound to collection of these cells. My control automaticaly lays out these cell into grid (9x9 board).

When i place my control with items everything looks good and cells are present.

Problem is when i try to print my control using document paginator. Control is printed but it is empty, no items present. It looks like control needs somehow to be redrawn or notified to update itself and to load binded values. Any clues please?

This is how i generate my control on the fly before passing it to document paginator ehich is used to place multiple controls on page:

```
private UIElement generateGridControl(SudokuFile file, int row, int column)
{
    //Contsruct control
    View.GridControl.GridControl grid = new View.GridControl.GridControl();

    //Create sudoku data from provided file
    Grid model = new Grid(file.Type, file.ID);
    model.setValues(file.Data);

    //Create new viewmodel for my control and inject it to control
    grid.init(new GridVM(model), file.Save);

    //Set appearance
    grid.Width = 500;
    grid.Height = 500;
    grid.showLabel(true);

    //Create viewbox used to stretch control to desired size and wrap it around my usercontrol
    System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox box = new System.Windows.Controls.Viewbox
                                                  {Stretch = System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform, Child = grid};


    System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetRow(box, row);
    System.Windows.Controls.Grid.SetColumn(box, column);

    box.Margin = new Thickness(5);

    return box;
}
```

Comment: I don't know about document paginator at all, but i guess that your ViewBox never gets a complete layout/render cycle. Try `box.UpdateLayout()` before returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ViewBox needs an initial layout to be calculated. Call

```
box.UpdateLayout();
```

before returning from `generateGridControl`. Keep in mind that [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx) will not generally force a layout update, but only affects elements where `IsMeasureValid` or `IsArrangeValid` is false. Anyway, here it will work, since it is the initial layout.

Answer (score 1):

Printing in WPF still strikes me as somewhat black magic. There are a couple of pitfalls that I've been exposed to. One is if the control is not set into a visible portion of the screen and allowed to render, the control tends to not print correctly. Things like layout transforms will fail if the control is not rendered onto the screen for instance. Another thing that helps is to call Measure and Arrange on the item you're trying to print.

```
grid.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
grid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, grid.Height, grid.Width));
```

Comment: I do call measure and arange and controls are visible on the screen. There are visible bondaries and background of control, but control is empty - like there ire no items contained.

Comment: UpdateLayout is not a guaranteed fix. Read the note at the end of this MSDN article. [MSDN Update Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx). If your layout gets more complicated it may start failing.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. For my needs it should not be problem. However if there is more complicated layout it should be problem. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's an issue I've looked at and still aren't comfortable with. There is an update complete event that fires which you could listen for. However, even that event doesn't give me any confidence. As it will fire for events even when they happened automatically so there is no guarantee your updatelayout call is the one that got completed. If you find a good solution I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @Mark, i guess you've tried all possible combinations of `InvalidateMeasure`, `InvalidateArrange` and `InvalidateVisual`. Would it be solution to draw the control into a `RenderTargetBitmap` before printing?

Comment: I have heard that as a valid way of doing it. Especially for print previews since ideally you wouldn't be allowing the user to change the preview directly. Unfortunately I do have the requirement of allowing the user to edit the preview and therefore the bitmap wouldn't work for what I'm doing but it may work for you.